# Localization code throwing unexpected exceptions in java

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, resourcebundle

I'm working on a project for school. Part of the prompt for the application specifies that I'm supposed to add localization to the log in page to translate the text in to two other languages. I don't have any experience with localization and Internationalization so I looked up a tutorial on YouTube that you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0educ2nosg&t=2s).

The tutorial is slightly simpler than what I'm trying to do, but I thought that I extrapolated the information effectively. What I'm about to post is just a test to see if I could get the log-in prompt text to change language, based on a radio button selection by the user. Here is my log in controller class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LogInController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label logInPrompt;

@FXML
private TextField userNameField;

@FXML
private TextField passwordTextField;

@FXML
private RadioButton english;

@FXML
private RadioButton spanish;

@FXML
private RadioButton french;

@FXML
public void Login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    if (userNameField.getText().equals("user") && passwordTextField.getText().equals("password")) {
        logInPrompt.setText("Log in successful!");

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } else {
        logInPrompt.setText("Log in Failed");
    }
}

public String enLang = "en";

public String spLang = "sp";

public String frLang = "fr";

public String unitedStates = "US";

public String mexico = "MX";

public String france = "FR";

Locale us = new Locale(enLang, unitedStates);
ResourceBundle rbEn = ResourceBundle.getBundle("C195/MessageBundle_en_US", us);

Locale mx = new Locale(spLang, mexico);
ResourceBundle rbSp = ResourceBundle.getBundle("C195/MessageBundle_es_MX", mx);

Locale fr = new Locale(frLang, france);
ResourceBundle rbFr = ResourceBundle.getBundle("C195/MessageBundle_fr_FR", fr);

public String enLogIn = rbEn.getString("logInPromptEN");

public String spLogIn = rbSp.getString("logInPromptSP");

public String frLogIn = rbFr.getString("logInPromptFR");

public void langSelect(){
if (english.isSelected()){
  logInPrompt.setText(enLogIn);
}else if (spanish.isSelected()){
  logInPrompt.setText(spLogIn);
}else if (french.isSelected()){
  logInPrompt.setText(frLogIn);
}
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

}
```

Here is an example of one of my properties files, the other two are the same except they are for the other two languages:

```
logInPromptSP = Ingrese su nombre de usuario y contraseña:
```

The application runs if I comment out the localization code, but if I run it without the comment I get a list of exceptions and errors a mile long, very few of which I'm familiar with.

To try to figure this problem out, I went back and read through the Localization and Internationalization portion in my OCP study guide, and I searched through StackOverflow using search terms similar to the title of my question.

Any help anyone could offer me on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Also just a quick note: This is the first question I've ever posted on StackOverflow and I read the guidelines but I'm a complete noob at both programming and at using StackOverflow. So please kindly let me know if the way that I formatted my question or the problem I asked about is in any way inappropriate.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Forbes\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\C195 jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\build\built-       jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file:     C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
Deleting directory C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\lib
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 13 files to      C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\run302791547
jfx-project-run:
Executing      C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\run302791547\C195.jar using     platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav    a:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.j    ava:389)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav    a:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917    )
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImp    l.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1343441044.run(Unknown     Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    file:/C:/Users/Forbes/Documents/NetBeansProjects/C195/dist/run302791547/C195.jar!/c195/LoginXML.fxml:10

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2583)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
at c195.C195.start(C195.java:13)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherIm    pl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$54/1038706898.run(Unknown      Source)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:    326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/355629945.run(Unknown      Source)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/722855603.run(Unknown      Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:29    4)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1915503092.run(Unknown     Source)
at     com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at     com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1963387170.run(Unknown     Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base      name C195/MessageBundle_en_US, locale en_US
at      java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
at c195.LogInController.<init>(LogInController.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorI    mpl.java:62)
at       sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorA    ccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
at      javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.ja    va:967)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
... 22 more
Exception running application c195.C195
Java Result: -1073741819
Deleting directory     C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\run302791547
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Here is the updated stack trace after following your advice.

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Forbes\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\C195 jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\build\built-     jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file:     C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
Deleting directory C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\lib
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 13 files to     C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\run1318536498
jfx-project-run:
Executing     C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\run1318536498\C195.jar      using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.j    ava:389)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav    a:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917    )
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImp    l.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1343441044.run(Unknown     Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Forbes/Documents/NetBeansProjects/C195/dist/run1318536498/C195.ja    r!/c195/LoginXML.fxml:10

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2583)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
at c195.C195.start(C195.java:13)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherIm    pl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$54/1361720784.run(Unknown     Source)
at      com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:    326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/355629945.run(Unknown     Source)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/722855603.run(Unknown     Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:29    4)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1915503092.run(Unknown     Source)
at     com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at      com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1963387170.run(Unknown     Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base     name MessageBundle_en_US, locale en_US
at     java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
at c195.LogInController.<init>(LogInController.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorI    mpl.java:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorA    ccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.ja    va:967)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
... 22 more
Exception running application c195.C195
Java Result: -1073741819
Deleting directory     C:\Users\Forbes\Documents\NetBeansProjects\C195\dist\run1318536498
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Comment: Are those runtime errors or compiler errors?  And what's the first one?

Comment: The most important thing about asking a Java question where an exception is involved: include the entire stack trace of the exception in your question.  In your case, include the entire stack trace of one of the exceptions.  The stack trace will tell us exactly which line of code is causing the problem, and in all likelihood, why it is occurring.

Comment: Of course. I'm sorry. Here is the full stack trace.

Comment: I added the stack trace to the original question. Thank you!

Comment: The exception tells us that there is something wrong with line 10 of LoginXML.fxml.  What is on that line?

Comment: Here is line 10 of LoginXML.fxml:

Comment: <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="c195.LogInController">

Comment: Even with that line the program runs if I comment out the localization code though.

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  I didn’t scroll down far enough.  The real underlying exception is: `java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name C195/MessageBundle_en_US`  This suggests your ResourceBundle property files are not being seen by your application.  The ResourceBundle name is relative to the classpath roo, not your project root, so try `ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle_en_US", us);` instead.  Make similar changes for the other getBundle lines.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm still getting a large stack trace though. I'm not sure how best to comment a stack trace so I'll try putting it in a comment, if that doesn't work well I'll append it to the original post.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the stack trace is too big to put in a comment. I'm appending the stack trace to the original post now